# Remove boot option in Windows Boot Manager that is not listed in bcdedit

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, grub, bcdedit

I've accidentally installed [grub2win](https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub2win/) in order to configure a multiboot setup witch a Linux distro. I've figured out that the correct way is to create an EFI partition and install the 'real' GRUB. This works fine: I can choose between my Linux distro and the windows bootloader.

Now I want to get rid of grub2win, but I've found no way of doing this. The grub2win bootloader does not appear in the bcdedit menu upon which all the tools rely to remove an entry in the windows boot manager. Grub2win comes with an option to uninstall itself but it doesn't work. I've also tried `bootrec \fixmrb` but that only removes the 'real' grub bootloader.

My question is: **How do I remove the *grub2win* entry in the *Windows Boot Manager*?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of Grub2Win. I'm a bit confused by your question, so to help you I need some more information.

Where does Grub2Win appear when you boot? As a standalone menu (EFI style) or as part of the Windows boot manager menu (BIOS style)?

You mention that the uninstaller "doesn't work". Is there an error message or some other symptom that indicates failure of the uninstall?

It would be helpful if you would run the Grub2Win diagnostics, zip up the C:\grub2\diagnose file and send it to me as an attachment. With the diagnostic information, I should be able to tell you what is going on.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: I've [attached](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IgiHIoaQomOYaFCZ_xzu8W1W42jlZLOV/view?usp=sharing) a zip containing 2 images: One shows the grub menu which is loaded first, the other the windows boot manager which is loaded when I chose Windows 7 in Grub. The text file bcdedit enum all.txt shows the entries of the boot menu prior to reinstalling grub2win. The diagnose folder is the one you asked for.
The uninstaller didn't give any kind of error.

Comment: Oddly enough the windows boot manager is only shown sometimes. Most of the time it is black for 30 seconds and then boots WIN7. The timeout seems to reset itself to 30 seconds automatically.
Thanks in advance,